# Is there any way that visas can be sent online?

Tags: visa, netherlands, schengen

I applied for a Dutch visa at the Dutch embassy in Sri Lanka, as a non-EU family member joining his spouse in the Netherlands, so they collected my biometric data and visa application form, and they told me that they will send the data to their regional office in Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia, and they will handle the case.

My question is after the visa is approved is there any way for the visa to be sent online? Or how do you think the process of this visa will be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The visa will have to be endorsed into the passport, so the visa cannot be sent online. Once a decision is made, then the Dutch Embassy will make contact with you.

Comment: Does that mean they also sent my passport to Kuala Lumpur?

Comment: I would imagine so and it should then be returned back to you through the Embassy.

Comment: @user8725 it's conceivable that the actual insertion of the visa sticker occurs in Sri Lanka, and only the decision processing happens in Malaysia.  Does it matter to you one way or the other?

Comment: It should not be.

Comment: They didn't send my passport, the embassy in Sri Lanka told me that once the visa approved the embassy in Malaysia will send the sticker via courier, then they will attach the sticker on my passport here in Sri Lanka!

Comment: In most cases that would be correct. To be honest, does not matter where it is issued, as long as the visa is granted for you.